# Why is my map not displaying the place name in the map after getting the current location?

Tags: javascript, maps, geocoding

I have made a map with getting the current location,inside the getPosition is getting also the place name which I also made a reverse geocoding that returns the place name from a coordinate, I wonder what's wrong my code that it did not return the place name and even the marker with my code for reverse geocoding.

In the console I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ1Qn.png)

```
<p id="curr" style="">current lat lng</p>
    function getPosition() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
    currentLatLon = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(...currentLatLon),
        zoom: 20
      });
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();       
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    document.getElementById("curr").innerHTML=currentLatLon;
        geocodeLatLng(geocoder,map,infowindow);
  });
}

 function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('curr').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124059/11742502